# noImplicitAny does not work on generic higher order function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the snippet below, typescript does not emit any error although there is an argument implicitly typed as `any`.

```
declare function constrainedHOF<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T): T;

// x is implicitly any, but typescript does not complain
const hof = constrainedHOF(x => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

My guess is that the problem is the type constraint `T extends (...args: any[]) => any`, which makes typescript think that it is an explicit `any`.

How to solve this properly, both keeping the generic type constraint to be "function of any type" and making typescript complain about implicit `any` when it encounters an accidentally untyped callback inside the `constrainedHOF`?

Tested in latest stable Typescript 3.9.2.

I prepared a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwGccBbEACQHkAxAHgBUA+ACjCgggCMowBrALnh0AlALoBuAFChIsBCnTY88MHgIYYULKhDBKtOvBAAPDCFTAC8JgDpbsAOYEBUVAE8A2gF0h8ALwN4F1dmVnYuXlERQUkJAHpY+AABDAIAWmMAB3AMdJgYHBh4VBwASWIMiCwwLAwAQTcJFVQ1eAALHEQcHD9CEnJqJiM-AIBvCXgJ5VUcCBBrCBx7QaFJAF8ViTiEjFasS2AcEEtijCny6C1AjhxkU6GOEC17eCxzqpqIV0CGppb2xB6v3Umm0ugGQ388DGkymzRmcwWSyMG3WkiAA) that demonstrates the problem including a check that the problem really comes with the generic constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `Function` interface?

```
// according to your declaration, you return a function, is that correct?    
declare function callbackHOF<T extends Function>(callback: T): T

// @ts-expect-error noImplicitAny
const callbackHofNonTyped = someHOF(x => {
    console.log(x);
});

const callbackHofTyped = someHOF((x: number) => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwGccBbEACQHkAxAHgBUA+ACjCgggCMowBrALnh0AlALoBuAFChIsBCnTY88MHgIYYULKhDBKtOvBAAPDCFTAC8JgDpbsAOYEBUVAE8A2gF0h8ALwN4F1dmVnYuXlERQUlpaDgkNExcfFDObh49ekMTMwt4KkTFVBC2NIjBKLoJCQB6GvgAAQwCAFpjAAdwDDaYGBwYeFQcAElidogsMCwMAEE3CRVUNXgACxxEHBw-QhJyaiYjPwCAbwl4c+VVHAgQawgcewOhSQBfZ+q6+AwVrEtgHBAliGGEuY2gWkCHBwyBBhw4IC09ngWDBk2mEFcgXmi2Wa0Q2xx6k02l0+0O-ngpwulyW11u90eRneb0ktXqTVaHS6PT6AyGo3GaNm2NUINS4Qy6wAcng6K5OsBtkRSHoDkdKWcLji6XcHk9Xu8FqLlKUJWR1nKFUrdqqDgJUMhiPCYD4KVStVcbrrGcznkA)

Comment: Thanks! it really works. I just remember I saw somewhere that using the `Function` type is deprecated, but I'm not able to find a reliable source of that now. Also it will not cover all cases, like `<T extends (foo: number, ...args: any[]) => any>`, but for my case it is enough :)

Comment: I've found first problem with Function. TS cannot work anyhow with the function type, which is needed in most HOFs somehow. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIwIYCcDWAhApsOdXAHgBVFcAPKXMAEwGdEAxcaeMAPgAoJUAbfmgiYAXIlIBKceQDeAKERLERKCHRJuAOh0YA5g3EAFDKgC2uGugZlOkxAF5OiBcrcoMmbpIDci90qq6kh8gsJeOlr6DL7+SgC+8olAA)